# How to update a table from a another table

Tags: oracle

I have one table A has column (id, field_1,field_2),
and another table B has column (id,field_2)

Now I want to merge table B to A, that means i want to update field_2 in table A to value of table B. So how to implement that ? BTW I am using oracle

Thanks

Comment: Do both the tables contain same number of records?

Answer (score 30):

An alternative approach to the co-related subquery (suggested by Kerri) would be to use the MERGE statement, which *might* be more efficient than the subselect (which can only be verified by looking at the execution plan of both statements).

```
MERGE INTO table_b 
USING 
(
  SELECT id,
         field_2
  FROM table_a
) ta ON (ta.id = table_b.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET table_b.field_2 = ta.field_2
```

Comment: The only restriction to the `MERGE` statement is that you cannot update the column on which it is joined, i.e. you cannot update the column used in the `ON` clause.

Comment: This worked for me, updated 2.5 million rows vs. attempting the sub-query method which ran for maybe 45 minutes before erroring with `ORA-01555: snapshot too old`

Answer (score 15):

Not *exactly* sure what you're after on this one, but this should work as a one-off, or continuous via a scheduled job:

```
UPDATE table_a a
   SET field_2 = ( SELECT field_2
                     FROM table_b b
                    WHERE b.id = a.id )
;
```

Now, each time the above is executed, it will do it across all rows in the table. If this is something you need to do all the time, I would suggest something else, but for a one-off or very small tables it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this successfully using one table in user1 from another table in user2:

```
update user1.table1 a
set a.field1 = (
  select b.field1
  from user2.table2 b
  where a.field1=b.field1
)
where <condition for update user1.table1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger on tableB that updates tableA every time field_2 on tableB is updated. Check here for more info on creating triggers - http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#BABCIBBJ

Comment: Not relevant answer