# Update table with value from another table

Tags: mariadb, update, table

I have two tables:

```
   AudiTable
Id    Audi_cod   status      marke1
1         011      mid        Null
2         022      mid        Null
3         033      mid        Null


     RenoTable
Id         Model    marke2
1           N1        R1
2           N2        R2
3           N3        R3
```

I have this query:

```
 UPDATE AudiTable
        INNER JOIN RenoTable ON AudiTable.Id = RenoTable.Id
        SET status = 'good', AudiTable.marke1=RenoTable.marke2
        WHERE RenoTable.Model = N3 and AudiTable.Audi_cod=011
```

How do I take a value from one row and put it in a different row?

Comment: "different row" -- how will that row be identified?

Answer (score 0):

Using Oracle

```
MERGE INTO AudiTable
USING 
(
  SELECT
    id,
    marke2,
    model
  FROM RenoTable
) TA ON (TA.ID = AudiTable.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET AudiTable.STATUS = 'good',AudiTable.MARKE1=TA.MARKE2 
    where TA.MODEL ='N3' and AudiTable.audi_cod=033;
```

Source:
[How to update a table from a another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/how-to-update-a-table-from-a-another-table)

Comment: Sorry didn't notice it was mariadb.

Comment: i want to update just one value from AudiTable using one value from RenoTable. how can i do that using MariaDB